# Internet Explorer doesn't execute jQuery.load (Firefox does)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to make an really simple CMS system, so far so good.
But now when I'm trying to load an editing page into a `div` (`.load` - jQuery) IE doesn't display it, Firefox does.

Here is my loading code

```
function edit_item(id){
    $('#row_'+id).load("actions/edit.php?id="+id, function(response, status, xhr) {
      if (status == "error") {
        var msg = "Sorry but there was an error: ";
        $('#row_'+id).html(msg + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
      }
    });
}
```

And here's the page I am trying to load

```
<?php
include('connect.php');
$item = resultset;
?>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    $("#datepicker").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
    var currentdate = $("#currentdate").val()
    $("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', currentdate);

});
</script>
<form method="POST" action="actions/update.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="currentdate" value="<?=$item['datum']?>">
    <table style="border: 1px solid black; margin-left: 10px; width: 620px;">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Titel</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="titel" class="input" style="width: 560px;" value="<?=$item['titel']?>"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Datum</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="datum" class="input" id="datepicker" style="width: 560px;"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Bericht</td>
            <td><textarea name="inhoud" class="input" style="width: 560px; height: 300px;"><?=$item['inhoud']?></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Foto's</td>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="foto[]">
                <input type="file" name="foto[]">
                <input type="file" name="foto[]">
                <input type="file" name="foto[]">
                <input type="file" name="foto[]">
                <input type="file" name="foto[]">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="toevoegen" value="Updaten" class="input" style="float:right; margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 5px;"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$_GET['id']?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="aktie" value="item">
</form>
```

Internet Explorer is giving me this error:

> Sorry but there was an error: 0 Error: Could not complete the
>   operation due to error c00ce56e.

**Solution:** `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` was doing the trick, however IE had it cached. When I cleared it - it started working again so thanks!

Comment: I like Dear StackOver(flowers)

Comment: Please post your solution below and then accept your own answer.  That's the most proper way to use this site when answering your own question.

Comment: Also, I see that @BenP's post leads to answer. You should upvote him and accept that instead (he needs to improve his answer as well).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Googling the error code seems to suggest the problem is the encoding of the XHR response.

> If you set encoding headers for XMLHttpRequests to header(‘Content-Type’ , ‘text/html; charset=utf8‘); instead of header(‘Content-Type’, ‘text/html; charset=UTF-8‘); IE7 will give the nice and clear error c00ce56e.

See: http://blog.shpare.com/2008/03/04/error-c00ce56e-in-ie/

Comment: Assuming you're new to the community, here's few tips to improve your answer: 1) Do not answer a question with a question. :) 2) Add some code snippet/suggestion to your answer. You can quote it saying "as described in this post..." but just do not send them to another link. I'm sure you'll get more upvotes if you follow these tips.

Comment: @Mrchief, yes good idea. I'll improve this answer, but I'm not sure it'll help the upvotes/accept - I already received a (now deleted) reply from Delano de Rooij saying my reply was not helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

> As of version 2.6, MSXML passes all XML documents through Mlang.dll to
>   verify their encoding. If Mlang.dll encounters a non-standard encoding
>   string, it returns an error.
>
> "ISO8859_1" is the canonical representation of the Latin-1 character
>   encoding string in the Java language and class libraries. The standard
>   that is defined by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority, however,
>   is "ISO-8859-1", which is not an accepted alias.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304625

Check you content-type's charset.